# вызов activity из сервиса

Tags: java, android

Не получается вызвать activity из сервиса и broadcast ресивера.
Выдает ошибку ActivityNotFoundException. 
Код вызова активити

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intentIntent);
```

Код этой же активити в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name="app.six.MActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_adm"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Вообще не могу понять в чем причина. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сможет? В гугле читал, на англоязычной версии форума тоже смотрел. Ничего так и не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтоб запустить активити из сервиса достаточно поставить флаг, те сказать какое у него будет место в стеке активити (простыми словами). Пример:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(myService, myActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myService.startActivity(intent);
```

Что касается вашей проблемы, у вас имя активити `"app.six.MActivity"`, а вы хотите открыть `MActivity.class`

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Сейчас попробую. Просто на некоторых форумах рекомендовали использовать в манифесте имя активити вместе с названием пакета. Думал это поможет. Так же Пробовал запускать с именем .MActivity. Тот же результат.

Comment: Почему-то когда пишу название сервиса в интенте, Название подчеркивается красным. Выдает ошибку. Не подскажете в чем причина? Запуск активити пишу в методе onStartCommand

Comment: Вы добавьте код, вашего myActivity.class и кусочек где стартуете сервис, мб там что-нить. Но ошибка говорит сама за себя активити не найдено, те или вы забыли прописать в манифесте или нет метода onCreate в жизн цикле

Comment: Активити в данный момент пустой вообще, который создается андроид студией по умолчанию. Код запуска сервиса из броадкаст ресивера сейчас добавлю

Comment: Что-то не получается нормально вставить этот код.

Comment: Ребята. Кто может. помогите пожалуйста. Так и не могу решить проблему. Вообще ничего не понимаю. Ситуация такая. Человек дал мне код. Код написан был давно. Мне нужно этот код подправить и дополнить функциями. Я пытался сделать все это просто в отдельном проекте. В отдельном все получилось. А тут ничего не получается. В манифесте все прописано как надо. Активити все есть. А ошибку выдает. Ну что это может быть. Ну подскажите кто может.

Comment: зайдите ко мне в профиль, в вк скиньте проект на depositfile к примеру, я за 5 мин сделаю вам. можно не целый проект а просто активити который хотите открыть и сервис в котором вызов происходит; у ваc же именно эта часть не работает, и откуда сервис вызывается, хотя это не имеет значения, судя по ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Завтра тогда днем скину Вам обязательно.

Comment: Андрей. В общем разбирался в этом всю ночь. И заметил одну тенденцию. Может Вы подскажет?. Когда первый раз активити вызывается, то все хорошо. Если оно вызывается второй раз, то уже его никто не может найти. Место вызова значения не имеет. Вызывал из разных участков кода.